# Monic polynomial with integer coefficient and root constraints

Tags: polynomials, roots

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $\epsilon > 0$, can we always find an integer $n$ and a monic polynomial $f$ of degree $n$ with integer coefficients and complex roots $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ such that $|x_1-x| + \sum_{i=2}^n|x_i| < n \epsilon$?

Namely, we are looking for a polynomial where exactly one root is very close to x while the other roots are close to 0.

If so, is there an efficient way to compute such a polynomial?

The motivation is in finding integer recurrences that closely approximate a geometric growth with a factor $x$.

Comment: Does it? n can depend on epsilon

Comment: Got it, my first comment was wrong, thx for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is YES. Let $n=\lfloor \frac{1}{\epsilon} \rfloor$
so that $n\epsilon \geq 1$. Then, you can take $x_1$ to be the nearest integer to $x$ (so $|x_1-x|\leq 1 \leq n\epsilon$) and $x_2=x_3=\ldots=x_n=0$, and $f(t)=(t-x_1)(t-x_2)\ldots(t-x_n)$.

Comment: Well, it's clearly correct but it also means I clearly mispecified what I was after :)

Comment: Indeed. One possible way out is to try to minimize $max(|x_1-x|,|x_2|,\ldots,|x_n|)$.

Comment: That felt too strict initially. Maybe that's what I need though. And if it's really too strict, then epsilon for x1 and 1/2 for everyone else.